# Intersection SQL activerecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, intersection

I have an array and a SQL select statement that outputs a list very similar to the array.  I want to compare the results of the SQL statement and the array and count the similarities. I have done this:

```
array = [H1, H3, H4, H6, H9]
sql_statement = S.connection.select_rows("select name from bla") # should get H1,H4,H10 

i = 0
sql_statement.each do |sql|
if (sql & array)
i += 1
end
```

I want the answer to be 2 as H1 and H4 match.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution if you want to use direct SQL:

```
YourModel.count_by_sql(["SELECT count(*) FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column IN (?)", your_array])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the intersection of two arrays like this:

```
>> x = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
>> y = [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
>> x & y
=> [ 3, 4 ]
>> (x & y).size
=> 2
```